# XQuery Creating a Variable that contains a List Condition

Tags: xpath, xslt, xquery

I am very new to Xquery. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
let $numbers := ('1', '2', '3', '6')
let $answers := $document//answer[number/@number = 'ABC' and ........]
for $answer in $answers
    let...
```

After the **and** clause I have tried to put a condition for all the numbers in my numbers variable to create the answers variable.

```
and number[@number = $numbers]
```

And then later loop through all the answers that match 1, 2, 3 and 6.

Should I already be looping through numbers variable to create this answers variable that contains all my number picks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you showed a small but representative XML sample, together with the query result you are looking for. You can certainly compare a variable containing a sequence of items with the `=` operator with an attribute value, the comparison will be try as long as at least one item in the sequence is equal to the attribute.

Comment: That incoming sample is still yet to come unfortunately, but basically I want to collect everything to $answers variable that will match with every number I have in my $numbers list/sequence. And then in the for loop already access specific elements that came in and matched '1', '2', '3', '6'. Basically, this list numbers variable list would work as a filter of what inputs I want to let through into the answers list - that means there might be no incoming samples for '3', but I still want to get everything that does exist.

Comment: Hard to judge XPath or XQuery without seeing the XML data. It looks a bit odd that you compare e.g. `number/@number = 'ABC'` suggesting some `<number number="ABC"/>` exist in `answer` while at the same time checking e.g. `number[@number = $numbers]` which suggests there are also e.g. `<number number="1"/>` or `<number number="6"/>`. But if your sample data is like that the comparisons should be fine and work.

Comment: Oh I see now, this part seems to be fine, I seem to be running into error later in the answer loop when trying to access @number field with fn:normalize-space(...), but it returns: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument - so it somehow starts to access many multiple fields...

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest I would add a loop and a join like this :

```
let $numbers := ('1', '2', '3', '6')
let $answers := $document//answer[number/@number = 'ABC']

for $number in $numbers
   for $answer in $answers[number[@number = $number]]
    let...
```

or shorter :

```
let $numbers := ('1', '2', '3', '6')

for $number in $numbers
   for $answer in $document//answer[number/@number = 'ABC' and number[@number = $number]]
    let...
```